# Socket.io with typescript client side

Tags: typescript, socket.io

Is there some package or some way to use socket.io on client in-conjunction with typescript side but for some reason I cannot find any solution that works from my research. most of the posts are from like 2 years again so I would assume that would be why it is not still working now.

*Note:*

I am using webpack to place everything in a bundle. I am purely using typescript on client side and express and node.js on server side. I am trying to create a simple pong game.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some package or some way to use socket.io on client in-conjunction with typescript side

There isn't one. But I wrote one for alm.tools : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/4496f70cb925fe490f4fd5ca32ec90723a8976a8/src/socketLib/socketLib.ts

The concept it uses is document here : https://alm-tools.gitbooks.io/alm/content/contributing/async.html